# 127.0.0.1 works, localhost not - VH - Zend Ce, Mac

Tags: apache, macos, virtualhost

I am having weired problem, after adding my virtual host conf entry localhost is not working (getting forbiden 403) but 127.0.0.1 does (all accessed via browser - http), here you have my conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/MyData/__www/default"
ServerName localhost
<Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from All   
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes            
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The funny thing is that when I change allow from to:

```
 Allow from localhost
```

localhost works but 127.0.0.1 not, localhost is mapped properly in hosts file.

please help,

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some systems, `localhost` maps to an IPv6 address, `::1`. Try:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1,::1
```

Comment: not really, getting: The specified IP address is invalid. - on Apache restart

Comment: ok, I had to remove from hosts file: ::1 and on the Mac there is one more entry which needs to be removed: "fe80::1%lo0 localhost" - after that all works.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
127.0.0.1, ::1
          ^_______A space is needed before "::"
```